# Usage of an unlabeled break statement causes compilation to fail

Tags: java, javac

There are tons of answers on StackOverflow related to the of usage `break` statement in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html), yet unfortunately, I was not able to discover a clear explanation to my Java beginner type of a question.

```java
// Main.java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo: {
            break foo; // compiles and executes OK
        }

        bar: {
            // Java compiler produces an error at this point
            break;
        }


        // perhaps Java compiler complains on unused label, but...

        baz: {
            System.out.println("Hello World"); // compiles and executes OK
        }
    }
}
```

```bash
javac Main.java
```

```
Main.java:10: error: break outside switch or loop
            break;
            ^
1 error
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "An unlabeled break statement terminates the innermost switch, for, while, or do-while statement, but a labeled break terminates an outer statement."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 forms of the `break` statement, one without a label and one with a label.

Your first case compiles because there is a corresponding label of the same name labeling the statement to break from.

But in the second case, without a label, needs a specific kind of statement to break out of.  According to the [JLS, Section 14.15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15):

> A `break` statement with no label attempts to transfer control to the
> innermost enclosing `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement; this
> enclosing statement, which is called the *break target*, then
> immediately completes normally.
>
> A `break` statement with label *Identifier* attempts to transfer control
> to the enclosing labeled statement (§14.7) that has the same
> *Identifier* as its label; this enclosing statement, which is called the
> *break target*, then immediately completes normally. In this case, the
> break target need not be a `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` statement.
>
> **It is a compile-time error if a `break` statement has no break target.**

There is no enclosing `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for`; a block doesn't meet this requirement, so there is no break target.  Because there is no break target, there is a compiler error.

The break statement with an explicit label only requires a labeled statement, which can include a block with braces.